# x-domain error with relative links?

Tags: javascript, json, cross-domain, google-drive-api, osx-yosemite

I have an interesting problem that has me scratching my head a bit, and I have not been able to find anyone who has encountered the same issue.

I have a website that I am developing locally, built off a custom javascript framework that is tested and working.  As part of the setup, the site pulls in a JSON file to determine some structures.  All links within the entire project are relative links.

Last week, I zipped up my files, threw them on google drive, and downloaded them onto my personal laptop at home.  My home machine is running OS X Yosemite, my work machine is on Mavericks.

When I downloaded and unzipped the files on my Yosemite machine, suddenly Safari and Chrome both started kicking back cross domain errors on the XMLHttpRequest that pulls in the JSON file.  Nothing has changed in the file configuration, and again, all links are defined as relative links.

At home, I got around this by just setting up a quick vhost and throwing everything onto my development server.  However, I don't have admin rights on my work machine, and now that I have brought the files back to this machine to work, the issue has followed along to this machine.

I use the the same browsers to test that I use to browse online on this machine, so I'm not comfortable disabling the restriction in security settings, and, moreover, I see absolutely no reason why this should even be happening.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?  What could possibly have changed, and what could I possibly be overlooking?  Projects on this machine that use the same javascript framework (and therefore are making the exact same calls to the file system) work fine when launched from Finder.  It's only the files that were uploaded to google drive and subsequently downloaded to my Yosemite machine that are kicking back the error.

Any ideas or suggestions would be hugely appreciated.  This is proving to be a big pain and I'm rather flummoxed as to the cause.

Thanks!!

Comment: Oddly enough, this problem fixed itself just as mysteriously as it appeared.  The company uses Versions for it's version control, and I uploaded my changes, and then updated my local files to the most recent revision, and voila! Functionality returned. I'd love to know if anyone has a suggestion about what could have caused this.